# Implications of increasing the Auth token TTL / Best practices

Tags: laravel, token, jwt, ttl

Using JWT Auth + Laravel and Ionic for a mobile app.

I want to have the users stay logged in until they log out physically with a button. JWT has '60' (an hour) as its TTL for the token.

I know I could just increase this and be done, but I imagine there is a reason to having it only an hour by default.

There is lots of terms for refreshing tokens etc but can anyone give a quick summary of how to deal with long term tokens?

Do I set a refresh every 60 minutes, every request or is having a long TTL fine?

Comment: read about refresh token

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [jwt-auth package](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) wiki page on [authentication](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication). There is a middleware `Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken` the way this works is.

> This middleware will again try to parse the token from the request,
>   and in turn will refresh the token (thus invalidating the old one) and
>   return it as part of the next response. This essentially yields a
>   single use token flow, which reduces the window of attack if a token
>   is compromised, since it is only valid for the single request.

in my opinion as long as your application has fairly constant communication without long periods of inactivity ( more than your 60 min window ) this is the best way to go about keeping your token fresh.

If your not using the jwt-auth package you can still apply the logic you just need to pass back a new token in the header of your response, see the [RefreshToken Middleware](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/develop/src/Middleware/RefreshToken.php#L45) for an example of this.

Comment: I have read the Wiki a few times, would I apply both the jwt.auth and jwt.refresh middlewares on my routes? And if someone has been inactive longer than 60 minutes, will this re authenticate them?

Comment: @Lovelock it won't. you probably want long lived tokens, just make sure you use a private password client + SSL only